# Is Viewstate Client side state or Sever side state

Tags: asp.net

I read conceptly viewstate is client side state. It persists the data between round trip. But the Process of viewstate is  on server side in the page life cycle (load Postview state and saveviewstate). This is creating little bit confusion. Is this client side or sever side state management

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is client side, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx

Specifically the Client-Side State Management Options section.

Answer (score 1):

It is stored at client side (or in the page itself) but processed by server and JavaScript libraries.